# I am having trouble with this python programme

Tags: python, error-correction

I am a beginner and am trying to write a piece of code that tells you how long the longest substring is that is written in alphabetic order.

So far I have:

```
    s = 'azcbobobegghakl'
    n=len(s)
    i=0
    longest=1


    while i<n+1:
        print(s[i])
        if s[i] < s[i+1]:
            longest+=1
            i+=1
        else:
            i+=1

    print(longest)
```

However I keep getting an error:

> IndexError: string index out of range

Could somebody please tell me where I am going wrong and how to fix it

Comment: use a meaningful title. Millions of people have problems with their python programs, but they all find a more specific title.

Comment: Python indexing is zero-based. if `i` is equal to `len(s)`, it's out of range. `i+1` is even more out of range.

Comment: I wrote while i<n+1 where n=len(s). Does that not mean that i will always be within range?

Comment: It does not, and that was part of what I was hinting at.

Comment: Could you explain to me why it is out of range?

Comment: Because it will still go into the loop when `i == n` -- one past the end. But you'll have a problem with the previous iteration because of the `s[i+1]`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
s = 'azcbobobegghakl'
n=len(s)

longest=1
counter=1

for i in range(len(s)-1):
    print(s[i])
    if s[i] < s[i+1]:
        counter+=1
    else:
        if counter > longest:
            longest = counter
        counter = 1
if counter > longest:
     longest = counter

print(longest)
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your condition in while loop like this

## Change

```
 while i < n-1:

  Change n+1 to n-1
```

## Reason:

```
   n is length of string
   Index of string : 0,1,.....,n-1
   In your program one iteration  will check next element also:
    ie:  when I == 0 , it will access str[0], str[1]
    Like i == n - 2 , str[n-2], str[n-1]
    Now if your condition is i less than n +1 then it will check 
    i == n , str[n], str[n+1] it will give you index out of range 
    because str[n+1] doesn't exist
```

Comment: Error is in line `if s[i] < s[i+1]:` so if condition in while loop is `i < n` then in last iteration `i`  will be equal to `n-1`  and it will still throw index error in if condition in `s[i+1]` .

Answer (score 0):

Error that you are getting is `IndexError: string index out of range` in line 11 `if s[i] < s[i+1]:`. The problem is that `i` in while loop will become too big (bigger than n-1). Your loop condition should be `while i<n-1:` and **NOT** `while i<n-1:` like others have suggested in their answers. You are checking for each character in string `s` if it is smaller (if it appears before in alphabet, actually, Python check if it has a smaller Unicode code, so you need to use only lowercase or only uppercase letters) than the next character in the string. And you can check this for all characters in a string except the last one because the last character doesn't have successor (there is no next character after last one). That's why you should have `i<n-1:` in your while loop.

Full working code:

```
s = 'azcbobobegghakl'
n=len(s)
i=0
longest=1
print(n)


while i<n-1:
    print(s[i])
    if s[i] < s[i+1]:
        longest+=1
        i+=1
    else:
        i+=1

print(longest)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
s = 'azcbobobegghakl'
n=len(s)
i=0
longest=1

while i<n:
    print(s[i])
    if i == n-1:
       break
    elif s[i] < s[i+1]:
       longest+=1
       i+=1
    else:
       i+=1

print(longest)
```